# Querying Address Field On User Object , Giving Error On Compilation OF test classes in sandbox?

Tags: apex, soql, user

```
User fromUser = [SELECT Name, CompanyName, Email, Address, FirstName, LastName, Phone 
                   FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
```

this problem occurs when client installed our package and then complile their classes, its not occured at my dev org

also i tried some solutons like update api versions and trying to resave their classes with updated api versions , ...still the problem ocuurs

Comment: if you check this doc https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_user.htm here country, state, street etc fields are there but Address field is not present so check with those fields

Comment: @Ratan  this problem occurs when client installed our package and then complile their classes its not occured at my dev org

Comment: also i tried some solutons like update api versions and trying to resave their classes with updated api versions , ...still the problem ocuurs